# Edge of the graph is not selected

Tags: python, python-3.x, graph, pyvis

To plot the graph, I use the following code:

```
from pyvis.network import Network
import csv
got_net = Network(height='900px', width='100%', bgcolor='#222222', font_color='white')
got_net.barnes_hut()

with open('test.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in spamreader:
        id_, channel, message = row
        src = str(id_)
        dst = str(channel)
        msg = str(message)
        got_net.add_node(src, src, title="ID: " + src, size=5)
        got_net.add_node(dst, dst, title="Channel: " + dst, size=10,
                         physics=False, shape='triangle')
        got_net.add_edge(src, dst, label=msg)
got_net.force_atlas_2based()
got_net.show_buttons(filter_=True)
got_net.show('./test.html')
```

I get the result:

[image]

But when I try to change the color of the edge of the graph, it doesn't work:

[image]

Could you tell me please, what am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to make the edges also have a different color when they are selected? Thank you.

my csv file:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, in my case, when constructing an `edge`, you must specify the following:

`color=dict(highlight={'background': 'red'})`

final version:

`got_net.add_edge(src, dst, label=msg, color=dict(highlight={'background': 'red'}))`